# Multiple builds using the same YAML file

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an Ionic application that should be built for ios and android. The application is also built for multiple customers where each customer has its own theme.

The only difference between the builds are the platform and one environment variable. Therefore I would like to reuse the YAML file and NOT create a separate build for each customer and copy the YAML file between them.

Is it possible to trigger multiple builds and set variables for each build using the same YAML file?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Have you actually tried setting it up? It should be straightforward. If not, refer to the documentation. If you have a specific question, feel free to ask it.

Comment: Also: Defining multiple jobs in the same YAML file that reference a separate, parameterized YAML file containing your build steps will also work.

Comment: you should probably look for templating in azure devops yaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with **4c74356b41** , as 4c74356b41 said , you could use templates to define your logic once and then reuse it several times.

You can reuse steps,jobs,Stage,Variable through templates. For example,Step re-use:

File: templates/npm-steps.yml :

```
steps:
- script: npm install
- script: npm test
```

File: azure-pipelines.yml :

```
jobs:
- job: Linux
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-16.04'
  steps:
  - template: templates/npm-steps.yml  # Template reference

- job: macOS
  pool:
    vmImage: 'macOS-10.13'
  steps:
  - template: templates/npm-steps.yml  # Template reference
```

You can reuse one or more steps across several jobs. In addition to the steps from the template, each job can define additional steps.

**Passing parameters**

File: templates/npm-with-params.yml :

```
parameters:
  name: ''  # defaults for any parameters that aren't specified
  vmImage: ''

jobs:
- job: ${{ parameters.name }}
  pool: 
    vmImage: ${{ parameters.vmImage }}
```

When you consume the template in your pipeline, specify values for the template parameters.

```
jobs:
- template: templates/npm-with-params.yml  # Template reference
  parameters:
    name: Linux
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-16.04'

- template: templates/npm-with-params.yml  # Template reference
  parameters:
    name: macOS
    vmImage: 'macOS-10.13'
```

For details ,please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops).